# Capture periods but not inside links

Tags: javascript, regex

I've scoured this fine site for both outright solutions and snippets that could *lead* to a solution, with no results.

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
(?!(\b[\w]+:\/\/.*?))\B\w+\.
```

In this snippet `Here is some sample text with a URL: http://stackoverflow.com. I would prefer to select periods outside of URLs though.` the following captures are happening:

- `tackoverflow.`
- `om.`
- `hough.`

I just want the period after the URL and the last one in the sentence. I'm using JavaScript so I don't have access to negative lookbehinds (which seems real useful but maybe we'll get them someday).

Comment: What *matches* do you want, or do you not really care as long as the last matched character is a `.` not in a URL? (eg, matching `om.` and not `com.` seems odd, is that really OK?)

Comment: If your sentences are properly formatted, then a period should always have a space following it, or EOL anchor `$` if it's not within a URL. Unless you're matching fractional numbers or something along the lines.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I want periods, but not if it matches inside a link/url.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs That's a good point, I added `\s` at the end of my regex but I still have the problems of the above captures happening.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to capture? Just the period and nothing else?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Just a period. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a positive lookahead to assert that either a space or EOL comes after your period.

```
\.(?=\s|$)
```

[See it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HzIBCl/1/)

- `\.` Matches a literal period
- `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead, that will assert either a space `\s` or EOL `$` comes after your period. This would never be the case in a URL which is why it works.

If you wanted to be less restrictive, you can replace your lookahead with any non-alphanumeric character instead of a space. Here's an alternative:

```
/\.(?=[^a-z0-9]|$)/igm
```

[See it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HzIBCl/2)

Comment: I didn't realize your comment earlier was to replace the entire regex I made with _yours_. Well, this is perfect, thank you.

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby The `\.(?=\s|$)` is not perfect due to the alternation in the lookahead. `\.(?!\S)` is perfect. Same with `\.(?=[^a-z0-9]|$)`, it must be written as `\.(?![a-z0-9])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression: `([\w]+:\/\/[^\s]+)([\.](?=\s|$))`

Example for decorating urls minus periods as a markdown hyperlink:

```js
const expression = /([\w]+:\/\/[^\s]+)([\.](?=\s|$))/g;

const input = `http://stackoverflow.com.
In this snippet Here is some sample text with a URL: http://stackoverflow.com. I would prefer to select periods outside of URLs though.
http://stackoverflow.com`;

const output = input.replace(expression, (match, url, period) => `[${url}](${url})${period}`);

console.log(output);
```